# How to add a new version of an existing apt package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I´ve come across a problem while trying to add a new version of an Package in my own apt repo

I have created my own repository with an .deb package using `reprepro`. in /pool it references my Package. I created the repo with Version 0.1. Now i Have altered the scripts and want to update it to Version 0.2. So i include the new .deb File to the specific /pool-Entry. Then i try to update the Package and Package.gz Files via `dpkg-scanpackages`. It adds the new Version of my package to the files. Now if i want to install a lower version of the package on an diffrent PC via `apt install Package=0.1` i get the error:

`Version 0.1 for Package was not found`

What have i done wrong? How can i add an Versioning in my apt repo?

thx for awnsers

edit after @Nmath comment:
ok so here we go. I hope its more specific this time:
I have created a working apt-repository using reprepro. I can download the Package with apt after configuring the source. Now i want to publish a new Version. How can i add a new Version to the existing repository? Basically i want to achieve that its possible to use the command "apt install hello=0.1" as well as "apt install hello=0.2" with both Version 0.1 and 0.2 available

A more specific example:
I created a Hello World Programm. So i publish it via apt. so you can use "apt install hello_marske". you can now use "hello_marske" as a command to print "Hello World".  This is now Version 0.1
in the next step i changed the Hello World-Skript to take a name as an argument to print "Hello Marske" after using "hello_marske marske". This is now version 0.2. Now i want both those Versions available as an apt repo. So the user has the choice either to use "apt install hello_marske=0.1" as well as "apt install hello_marske=0.2" depending on what functionality the user wants.

To go even further i want to keep a script running that checks whether a new version is available and download that Version asap. But thats only a lookout what i want to achieve and not currently part of the question.

Comment: You should provide more details.  All of the details in this question are generic and vague. We can't work with that.  Include specifics instead of generalities. Your problem can't be identified without exact details.

Comment: ok so here we go. I hope its more specific this time: